# Vertical align a div on the page (using bootstrap?)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align a div within my page so that it sits directly in the centre at all times. I've searched the site, but can't see any solutions for centring in the page rather than just a div.

Using bootstrap (3.2.0) I can centre it horizontally, but not vertically!

Here is my code so far:

HTML

```
<div class="slide">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="logo col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                 <p>Test</p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.logo {
border: solid;
border-color: red;
border-width: 5px;
height: 200px;
}
```

I tried `verticle-align: middle;`, `margin:auto;` & `margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto;` to no effect.

The closest I can get is to use `margin-top: 20%;` but this doesn't shrink as the page height does.

Comment: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ --- there's nothing built with bootstrap that vertically centers as that is accomplished with various means based on the situation.

Comment: Do you have any CSS affecting the parent elements (row, container, & slide)? How are they positioned?

Comment: I'm afraid the methods mentioned in the article didn't seem to work for my situation. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. There is no CSS affecting the other elements, other than that from bootstrap e.g. `class="md-col-6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magical way in bootstrap to do it. You need a helper div wrapper in order to immolate a table structure.

```
<div class="slide">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="logo col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
             <div class="helper">
                 <span>Test</span>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

.logo {
 border: solid;
 border-color: red;
 border-width: 5px;
 height: 200px;
}
.helper{
background:#ccc;
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align:center;
display:table;
}
span{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: The div still appears at the top of the page I'm afraid. I even started a new blank project and pasted your code as it is (including the bootstrap link!)

Comment: Can you send me a link to that page that you just created?

Comment: `http://enhanceddd.com/vertical-align/index.html` There is the page, thank you for the help!

Comment: looks perfectly centered and vertically aligned in the middle to me on Chrome and firefox. What browser are you using?

Comment: I've tried both chrome and internet explorer. Screenshots at `http://i62.tinypic.com/14wr95v.png` & `http://i58.tinypic.com/2qa0ggx.png` respectively.

Comment: Hey, made a fiddle and it still doesn't seem to work... http://jsfiddle.net/kitsonbroadhurst/C9472/ Hope you can help!

Comment: This is a bit more tricky because you have to have a set height. The body and other divs height only extends to the height of the inner divs which doesnt mean the whole browser window. If you wrap your container in a helper div and make that display:table and height lets say 500px and width of 100%, then you can set your container display to table-cell and vertical-align middle and it should display centered. but if you want it to move up and down based on the size of the window you have to have more jQuery in there to read the window height and set the helper height to that

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm going to stick with `height: 20%` and look at a jQuery solution if it becomes a problem.